# Freetype 2. Is there a way to change the size of the font in pixels after you have loaded it?

Tags: c++, text, text-rendering, freetype2

So i'm playing around with creating a simple game engine in c++. I needed to render some text so I used this tutorial (http://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Text-Rendering) for guidance. It's using the library freetype 2.

Everything works great, text is rendering as it should. But now when i'm fleshing the ui out and is creating labels I would like to be able to change the size of the text. I can do so by scaling the text, but I would like to be able to do so by using pixels.

Here you can see the scaling in action:

```
    GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
    GLfloat ypos = y + linegap + (font.Characters['H'].Bearing.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

    GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
    GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
```

So in my method renderText I just pass a scale variable and it scales the text. But I would prefer to use pixels as it is more user friendly, is there any way I could do this in freetype 2 or am I stuck with a scale variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. It sounds like you want to regenerate the glyphs, re-rasterizing them at a higher resolution. Well, you have to actually *do that*. That means, whatever process you go through to get the glyph data must be done *again* when the size changes.

Comment: I feel stupid for not having thought about that but thanks Cornstalks, that worked great. The text looks not so great when the size is set lower that the one it generated with but I think thats because of the font I choose. Again, thanks Cornstalks!

Comment: @assasinDN: Good, glad it helped! I've moved my comment into an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to regenerate the glyphs at a different resolution, but instead want to specify scale as a unit of pixels instead of a ratio (i.e. you want to say `scale = 14 pixels` instead of `scale = 29%`), then you can do the following: Save the height value you passed to `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes` (which is 48 in the tutorial). Now if you want a 14-pixel render, just divide 14 by that number (48), so it would be `scale = 14.0f / 48.0f`. That will give you the scaling needed to render at a 14-pixel scale from a font that was originally generated with a 48-pixel height.

You might want to play with your OpenGL texture filters or mipmapping as well when you do this to improve your results. Additionally, fonts sometimes have low-resolution pixel hinting, which helps them be rendered clearly even at low resolutions; unfortunately this hinting information is lost/not used when you generate a high res texture and then scale it down to a smaller render size, so it might not look as clear as you desire.